# Jackson network, steady state

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, network-flow, network

My question is below:

> Consider a network of n queues with a Poisson arrival process of
>   parameter t from outside the network, and independent exponentially
>   distributed service times of parameters r1 to rn.
>
> Customer that first arrived to the network initally join queue i with
>   probability Pi (obviously there probabilities sum to one)
>
> A customer completeing its service at queue i will head to queue j
>   with probability Pij, or will leave the network with probability $$ P_{i, n+1} $$
>
> Let K(t) denote the queue length vector for each of the queues at time
>   t, and let $$ l = (k_{1},...,k_{2}) $$, k1 to kn is >= 0
>
> be a particular value of this vector
>
> Obtain p(k) = lim(t->inf) p(k,t) where p(k,t) = Prob[K(t) = k] in
>   terms of the parameters previously defined, and prove your result in
>   full detail

So I immediately tell that we are talking about the network going into a steady state.

To begin solving it I considered the small time interval delta t, where 1 packet may arrive, 0 arrive or many may arrive for each node. Each event has a probability. When we work through the maths it is possible to subtract from both sides of the equation

Ultimately I express $$ \frac{d}{dt}p(k,t)  = all-possible-events $$

In steady state the rate of change will be 0, therefore $$ \frac{d}{dt}p(k,t) = 0 $$.

This is where I am stuck. Now what do I do? I know from other reading that the result will be p(k) = product form where the nodes behave independently of one another (a powerful result). But how do I find p(k) from  $$ \frac{d}{dt}p(k,t) $$ to get p(k). I don't think I can just integrate, nor do I solve a differential equation. What should I do from here?

Let me know if you don't understand what I'm asking :)

I can do the proof afterwards

Thanks